# Stray instructions when reconstructing method using asm

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am using asm to modify the instructions of a MethodNode. My code constructs a graph from the methodNode.instructions. Using this graph, I rearrange and delete instructions. I then use the graph to generate a new list of instructions for the MethodNode. The problem is that the instructions still have values for .getNext() which results in stray instructions that are no longer contained in the graph to be added to the end of the methods instructions. This also causes a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when converting the InsnList to an array.

Example:

Initial instructions:

```
L0
 ALOAD 1
 LDC 1784196469
 INVOKEVIRTUAL dq.c (I)I
 ISTORE 2
 ILOAD 2
 IFNE L1
 GOTO L2
L3
 RETURN
L1
 ALOAD 0
 ALOAD 1
 ILOAD 2
 BIPUSH 15
 INVOKEVIRTUAL ac.f (Ldq;IB)V
 GOTO L0
L2
 GOTO L3
```

After changes in graph. These are the instructions that are added to methodNode.instructions after the list is cleared.

```
L0
 ALOAD 1
 LDC 1784196469
 INVOKEVIRTUAL dq.c (I)I
 ISTORE 2
 ILOAD 2
 IFNE L1
 RETURN
L1
 ALOAD 0
 ALOAD 1
 ILOAD 2
 BIPUSH 15
 INVOKEVIRTUAL ac.f (Ldq;IB)V
 GOTO L0
```

When .getNext() is called on the last instruction, this is the result:

```
org.objectweb.asm.tree.LabelNode@7a0ac6e3
```

As you can see the last instruction added (GOTO L0) has a value for .getNext()

When this MethodNode is saved and then decompiled this is the result. There is a stray GOTO statement to a nonexistent label.

```
L1 {
    aload1
    ldc 1784196469 (java.lang.Integer)
    invokevirtual dq c((I)I);
    istore2
    iload2
    ifne L2
    return
}
L2 {
     aload0 // reference to self
     aload1
     iload2
     bipush 15
     invokevirtual ac f((Ldq;IB)V);
     goto L1
     goto L3
}
```

How can I reuse instructions from the method if I am changing the order of them? Is this a bug or am I using asm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`InsnList`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/InsnList.html) is a linked list of [`AbstractInsnNode`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/AbstractInsnNode.html). Each instance of the `AbstractInsnNode` has a pointer called `next` that points to the next node in the list.

When you rearrange nodes in a list, you will need to take care of these pointers as well. In your case, the node for `GOTO L0` originally points to `L2`, and because its `next` pointer has not been updated during the rearrangement, it still points `L2` at the end.

There seems to be no easy solutions to update the `next` pointer. There is no setter method for it. The [`clear`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/InsnList.html#clear--) method doesn't do it. The `removeAll` method is not visible.

Some possibilities might be to (i) use [`remove`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/InsnList.html#remove-org.objectweb.asm.tree.AbstractInsnNode-) to remove all nodes from the list before reusing them; or (ii) construct new nodes for the new list.

Comment: I tried inserting all the AbstractInsnNodes in reverse order but the last one in the list still has a pointer to some stray instruction.

Comment: @user3552325 Sure, that's because the `next` pointer of the first node you inserted (which is later the last node in the list) hasn't been updated. How about using the method I mentioned to append a new node to the last node: `insert(last, newNode)`. (You can use e.g. `add` to add the first node into the list.)

Comment: I need a way to make the next pointer on the last node null. insert doesn't help with that.

Comment: @user3552325 I'm sorry. My bad. Please see the edit.

Comment: Removing each instruction from the list instead of using clear() fixed my problem.